# select2 dropdownlist doesnt close after clicking the "add" button

Tags: javascript, dropdown, jquery-select2

I have added a "Add new person" button in a select2 dropdownlist

The select2 code looks like this:

```
  $('#subFundSelection').select2({
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: 'Select a sub-fund',
            ajax: {
                url: '/FundInfo/SearchLegalEntities',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                allowClear: true,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data.legalEntities, function (obj) {
                            return { id: obj.Id, text: obj.Text };
                        })
                    };
                },
            },
            minimumInputLength: 2
        }).on('select2:open', () => {
            $(".select2-results:not(:has(button))").append('<button id="newPersonButton" style="width: 100%" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="CreateLegalEntity()">+ Add a new person</button>')
        })
```

A button is well added to the dropdownlist (I cant add a picture sorry)

and when I click this "Add new person" button I open a modal.

```
function CreateLegalEntity() {
  
   $('#CreateLegalEntityModal').modal('show');
}
```

Everything work fine, instead of the fact that the dropdown list doesnt close after the click and it appears in the top of the modal, until I click somewhere else in the screen.

Sorry for not attaching screenshots but the website doesnt allow me.

I have tried:

```
$(this).blur() 
$(".select2").trigger('blur') 
$(".select2").trigger('change')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of SELECT2 here [Methods | Select2](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods)

> The close method will cause the dropdown menu to close, hiding the selectable options:

```
$('#subFundSelection').select2('close');
```

Should do what your looking for

**EDIT**

You should be calling the `.select2('close')` method from the same identifier your are initially creating the element `.select2({params});`

eg: `$('#div1').select2()` so it should be `$('#div1').select2('close')`

Comment: Hi @slashroot, 
thanks for your response. I have added it in the 
    function CreateLegalEntity() {
       $('.select2').select2('close');
       $('#CreateLegalEntityModal').modal('show');
    }
but it doesnt seem to be working.
now it looks that even the modal doesnt open

Comment: EDIT: I have edited to be pointing straight to my <select> with ID and it WORKS!
$('#subFundSelection').select2('close');
Thank you buddy